# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s dealing with Appboy iOS integration

Tags: objective-c, architecture, armv7, xcode5.1

I am trying to integrate appboy into my Xcode 5.1.1 project. I have followed all the steps on their SDK integration page found here: http://documentation.appboy.com/SDK_Integration/iOS. I was able to successfully install the pods, but when I try to compile and run my project I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Appboy", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in CAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code causing this issue it the code to upgrade the app delegate found in CAppDelegate.m under the method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[Appboy startWithApiKey:@"(I PUT MY API KEY HERE)"
 inApplication:application
 withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your app target includes "$(inherited)" if it is overriding any of the settings of Pods.xcconfig. You can check this under **Build Settings** >> **Your App Target** >> **Other Linker Flags**.

[image]

If you need any additional support on this issue, feel free to contact support@appboy.com.